# Terminology for Permissions Operation

Tags: gui-design, intuition

We're working on a user security manager. In the app, there is an operation to overwrite a user's permissions with the permissions of another user, essentially:

1. Delete all permissions and group membership of the user being modified.
2. Copy all permissions and group membership of the selected user to the user being modified.

"Copy Permissions" doesn't describe that the user's current information is about to be overwritten.

We've mulled a little, and rejected the following:

- Assume
- Duplicate
- Overwrite

We want the language to inform and warn, but it needs to be brief. Is there a word for this operation that we're missing?

Comment: I am a developer and in our world if that is saved then it is called clone and if it is temporary it is impersonate.

Comment: Clone is pretty good. If you want to make an answer that'd be appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the word clone.

I am a developer and that is the word we use.
In many development languages that is exactly what clone means.

If it was just temporary the term developers would use the term impersonate.

For lack of something better I would use the technical term.

Please see the comments.  The OP asked be to add that as an answer.

Comment: Please see the comments.  The OP asked be to add that as an answer.

Comment: OP may have asked you to add it as an answer, but that doesn't mean it's a detailed enough answer for the site at just one line. You haven't covered off any explanation other than 'I'm a developer and it's what I do'. *Why* do you use that term? Do users understand it as well? Where does it come from? Is it a commonly used term? Explanation and context rather than just one-line answers are what this site is for. We're not here just to help one individual person, but to help *anyone* who finds this question in future. And they'll need detail and reasoning to find it useful.

Comment: I said we use as in developers - I thought that was an explanation of the basis for the why I would use clone.  And it was two not one line.  I edited to try and expand.

Answer (score 1):

I think 'import' or 'transfer' are the best terms to describe this, because you are essentially transferring data from one source to another, and 'importing' the new settings to the user.

Comment: Import is good, but not quite right, since importing doesn't usually also mean overwrite.Transfer implies moving them away from the their source, like transferring money from one account to another.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways

1. Search for the right word : "Match"
2. Provide a warning/note : Stay with "Copy" but put a warning message explaining that existing permission would be deleted and selected user's permission would be copied.